# How to implement Tokensregex based entity extraction in python

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I wanna use tokensregex feature of Stanford for basic entity extraction. But   don't have any idea how to use it through wrapper classes in **python** and where I can put my own regex rule to use it.

Most of the code and implementation I got were in java. Can you suggest any good tutorial or explain briefly? Till now I was using CRF models for Entity extraction.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to write rules files, run a Java server, and use our Python wrapper for accessing the server.

info about rules files:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

info about accessing a server in Python:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/python-stanford-corenlp

Very shortly we will be releasing a new Python package, so I'll update this info when that comes out.

Comment: I used above code mentioned in https://github.com/stanfordnlp/python-stanford-corenlp but getting error in **with corenlp.CoreNLPClient(annotators="tokenize ssplit pos lemma ner depparse".split()) as client:**   I have installed stanford corenlp as mentioned pip install stanford-corenlp and setup the environment variable in bashrc file as **export CORENLP_HOME="/home/stanford/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-02-27"**. I'm using anaconda python 2.7 for accessing stanford corenlp's recent version.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "corenlp1.py", line 4, in <module>
    ann = client.annotate(text)
  File "/home/saurabh/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/corenlp/client.py", line 225, in annotate
 ..... 
raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9000): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)